# PHP/SQL Converting timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am working on a simple website and I ran into a problem. I have a subscription based website and I have a date expired for when their subscription ends. This all works well, but when I tried to display the expiration date I ran into problems. The first 3 lines are what i have been trying. It seems as if the timestamp isnt correctly being transferred from the database because when I did my test at the button, this displayed the correct date. The top 3 lines always give me this: 1970/01/01

```
// Get Expiration Date
// Always gives me  1970/01/01
$datexpire  = "SELECT date-expire FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
$timestamp = mysqli_query($link, $datexpire);
$date = date("Y/m/d",$timestamp);

//This works
$timestamp2 = 1537847863;
$date2 = date("Y/m/d",$timestamp2);
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated

Comment: where is $intform defined ???

Comment: I changed it, forgot to get rid of that

Comment: You need to use backticks around `date-expire`  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: (not related to Q itself) Woah, I surely hope your `$_SESSION['username']` was sanitized before usage.

Comment: sanitized ?  @MilošĐakonović you mean protected against SQL injections right? Must read your the topicstarter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @RaymondNijland sure. Many things may end up in that `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Answer (score 0):

i think your code should be something like

```
 $datexpire  = "SELECT date-expire FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $datexpire);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
       $timestamp = $row['date_expire'];
       $date = date("Y/m/d", $timestamp);
       echo $date;
```

please check for column name.. if it is date-expire or date_expire ??? (dash or underscore ??)

Comment: if the username column is unique in the MySQL table you don't have to use the while statement.

Comment: This also returns the same date.

Answer (score 0):

[`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [`mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object or a boolean value.
You want to fetch a row from your given object, like so:

```
$datexpire = "SELECT `date-expire` FROM users WHERE username='{$_SESSION['username']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $datexpire);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$date = date("Y/m/d", $row["date-expire"]);
```

Comment: This still returns the same date.

Comment: The problem is this " Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:

    ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore) " see source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html you need backticks @user10251809 read the comments

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's another problem with the code, you are correct.

Comment: @user10251809 You should try my updated code. If it doesn't work as expected, please tell us the result of `var_dump($result, $row);`.